# Is it possible to download a Google Doc with command line without having to interactively authenticate?

Tags: macos, command-line, google-docs

Is it possible to download Google Docs (a mix of docs, spreadsheets, and slides) with command line (in macOS), and without having to authenticate interactively?

The files that I'd like to download are in someone else's Google Drive and have been shared with me, so I probably would need to authenticate using my Google credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a command line program or build it by your self. Here are some programs that might help you to get inspiration:

- [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp): command line program for Google Apps Script programmers
- [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM): command line program for Google Workspace administrators